# Why does the value not update?

Tags: angular

I ran into a problem where I am assigning a value (via a dynamic variable) to a property of an object inside of an array.  When the variable changes, the value doesn't update. Why doesn't it update, and is there another way I can implement this so it does update?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Brian';
  people = [{ name: this.name }];

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.name = 'Eric';
      console.log(people[0].name); // Brian
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just updating `this.name`. You also have to update `people` because `name: this.name` is not reference.

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.name = 'Eric';
      this.people = [{ name: this.name }];
      console.log(people[0].name); // Eric
    }, 5000);
```